# Plot only selected rows based on the "YES" or "NO" in the column

Tags: r

I would like to `matplot` only selected rows from the data frames. In both data sets you can find the column full of "YES" or "NO". I would like to `matplot` only rows (of course columns with the values) which have `YES` in the last column. Let me show you data first and later I give some more explanation what I expect to achieve.

```
> dput(c)
structure(list(Fr1 = c(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr2 = c(0.7, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Fr3 = c(1, 0.35, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr4 = c(0.1, 1, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0), Fr5 = c(0, 0.4, 0, 0, 1, 0), Fr6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 
0), Fr7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0), Fr8 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Fr9 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Fr10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.65, 0, 0.7), Fr11 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0, 1), w = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NO", 
"YES"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Fr1", "Fr2", "Fr3", "Fr4", 
"Fr5", "Fr6", "Fr7", "Fr8", "Fr9", "Fr10", "Fr11", "w"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant"), class = "data.frame")


> dput(d)
structure(list(Fr1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr2 = c(0.7, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Fr3 = c(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr4 = c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0), Fr5 = c(0, 0.1, 0, 0, 1, 0), Fr6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 
0), Fr7 = c(0, 0.8, 0, 0.7, 0, 0), Fr8 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    Fr9 = c(0, 0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0), Fr10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.65, 0, 0.7
    ), Fr11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 1), w = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NO", "YES"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Fr1", 
"Fr2", "Fr3", "Fr4", "Fr5", "Fr6", "Fr7", "Fr8", "Fr9", "Fr10", 
"Fr11", "w"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant"), class = "data.frame")
```

That's how those tables look like:

```
                  Fr1 Fr2  Fr3 Fr4 Fr5 Fr6 Fr7 Fr8 Fr9 Fr10 Fr11   w
Mazda RX4         0.2 0.7 1.00 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0 YES
Mazda RX4 Wag     0.0 0.0 0.35 1.0 0.4 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0 YES
Datsun 710        0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0  NO
Hornet 4 Drive    0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7   1   1 0.65  0.2  NO
Hornet Sportabout 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.5 1.0 0.3 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0  NO
Valiant           0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.70  1.0  NO

                  Fr1 Fr2 Fr3 Fr4 Fr5 Fr6 Fr7 Fr8 Fr9 Fr10 Fr11   w
Mazda RX4           1 0.7 0.2 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0   0 0.0 0.00  0.0 YES
Mazda RX4 Wag       0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.8   1 0.3 0.00  0.0 YES
Datsun 710          0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0 0.0 0.00  0.0  NO
Hornet 4 Drive      0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7   1 1.0 0.65  0.2  NO
Hornet Sportabout   0 0.0 0.0 0.5 1.0 0.3 0.0   0 0.0 0.00  0.0  NO
Valiant             0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0 0.0 0.70  1.0  NO
```

As you see I want to `matplot` only first two rows. The next task is to open pdf and  `matplot` first row from each table on the SAME GRAPH on one page and any other rows on the next page. So in every graph we should have 2 lines coming from different data sets but exactly the same row.

That's what I expect to see:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, using `c` as an object name isn't a good idea.

Furthermore, **your example** graphic (as of this writing) looks like a plot of the first **two rows** of the **first dataset**. I'm assuming that this is NOT what you want, and that you instead want what you've described in words.

So, my suggestion is to use the `mapply` function, which permits different rows from one dataset to be plotted together with different rows of the other dataset.

First, create a function that does what you want to do (note: your `c` is here `cc` and `d` is `dd`). This you will pass to the `mapply` function:

```
# xx is the row of cc you'd like to plot
# yy is the row of dd you'd like to plot
myfun <- function(xx, yy) {
    subCC <- cc[xx, -ncol(cc)]
    subDD <- dd[yy, -ncol(dd)]
    dat <- t(rbind(subCC, subDD))
    matplot(dat, type = "l", lty = c(2, 5), ylab = "Intensity",
        xlab = "Fraction size")
}
```

Then get the row indexes of your datasets that you'd like to plot

```
ccYes <- which(cc[, ncol(cc)] %in% "YES")
ddYes <- which(dd[, ncol(dd)] %in% "YES")
```

Then create a pdf with multiple pages passing the function above and the row indexes to `mapply`

```
pdf("lines.pdf")
mapply(myfun, ccYes, ddYes)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with the first part of your question. To plot just rows where `w = YES`, simply use R's subsetting ability to create a new object:

```
df1y <- df1[which(df1$w == "YES"), 1:(ncol(df1) - 1)]
df2y <- df2[which(df2$w == "YES"), 1:(ncol(df2) - 1)]
```

Where `df1` is the first `dput` output, and `df2` is the second `dput` output provided above. This assigns rows where `w = YES` and all columns to the new object, `df1y`/`df2y` and removes the final column (`w`) so there isn't a problem of coerced `NA`s.

I'm afraid I don't follow your second request. Could you clarify and I can try to help again, or perhaps someone else will answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's just about `matploting` rows from different data on the same graph. So according to the given example. Plot first row from `df1` and first row from `df2` on the same graph (2 lines on one graph) and so on for all of those `YES` rows.

Comment: What have you tried? Does `matplot(df1y[1, ], df2y[1, ])` produce what you're expecting for the first row? If so, I can edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: That's what I would like to get = 2 lines but the problem is that simple code doesn't work for my data. Just try it with the given example.

Comment: Why does 'simple code not work for your data'? Can you let me know what you've tried, and some illustration of what you expect the resulting graph to look like? Without these I'm lost because I'm not familiar with your particular situation.

Comment: I added the expected output. It doesn't work because of introducing NAs.

Comment: I think other answers are now more suitable than mine, but I have removed the final column (`w`) which at least removes the problems of `NA`s being introduced.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think it's good idea to name your first df something different than `c` as it is already an R function.

Second, you can subset your df as per @Phil suggestion. Once you have that, I assume you're getting an error from trying `matplot(df1y[1,],df2y[1,])` because of a couple reasons: First, you left the factor (yes / no) of the last column, and that forces NAs by coercion. Second, I guess you'll need to `rbind` it to properly display what you want, so:

```
matplot(t(rbind(df1y[1,1:11],df2y[1,1:11])),type="l")
```

From here on, you can make a loop to produce each row in a separate graphic.

G

Comment: It doesn't look like mine which I added to the question as expected output.

Comment: It does now. I transposed the `rbind` and now should look the same.

Comment: Could you just help me a bit with the loop as well ?